# find the eigenbasis of unitary transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory

$U$ is $n\times n$ unitary matrix, with orthogonal eigenbasis $v_1, \ldots v_n$ 
we construct a linear transformation: $T_U(X) = XU$ with the inner product $\langle A, B \rangle = \text{tr}(A^*B)$

I have proved that $T_U$ is unitary, and need to find an eigenbasis of $T_U.$ any hints please?